# How can to make a route accessible from only one of a list of middlewares

Tags: php, laravel, routes, breeze, laravel-middleware

...

```
    Route::get('/student_portal', [studentController::class, 'index'])
            ->middleware(['auth:junior_student', 'auth:senior_student']);
```

...

Now the problem is the I want this route to be accessible if either of the middle ware parameters is authenticated not when both of the parameter is authenticated, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `auth` middleware takes multiple parameters as the 'guards' to check:

```
middleware('auth:junior_student,senior_student')
```

The middleware will iterate through the guards and the first one to return a user will be set as the default guard and will let the user pass through.

Comment: Yeah, I need it to be authenticated with either one of the guards not both

Comment: then you want to be passing the guards like this example

Comment: Somehow that works but its not efficient as the login details brings up the portal of another student, the session doesn't seem to be invalidated anytime I logout